# How to make http GET/POST request in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How to http GET/POST request in ionic2 
and what are the data need to import ? 

I tried with [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)  but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**GET Example**

```
this.posts = null;

this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=2&sort=hot').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.posts = data.data.children;
});

console.log(this.posts);
```

https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/

**POST Example**

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let body = { 
  message:"do you hear me?"
};

this.http.post('http://spstest.000webhostap..., JSON.stringify(body), {headers: headers})
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
  });
}
```

https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-send-data-with-post-requests-in-ionic-2/

Good luck.

Comment: is it possible to assign the data to a local object so that i can show the values in the data to the html page

Answer (score 0):

For Creating the request firstly we need to add provider  by using this command :-

```
$ ionic g provider restService
```

here **restService** is the **ts** file name in which we write the below code for making request

```
   load() {

    console.log(' RestServiceProvider Load Method fro listing');
    let postParams = { param1 : '', param2: '' }
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.post("YOUR URL", postParams)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }
```

In the above code load() is the method of restService class.this method is help out to make the request .This method is called in your other class like this.

```
 this.restSrvProvider.load().then(data => {
       let mydata = data;
      });
```

For more knowledge you may go through the  [ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/) the